# New generated Maven PlayN project displays errors on android screen

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, playn

after hours and hours of search to get it running I'm stuck now. So what happened? I tried to dive into the PlayN framework to code my first game on android. With a little struggle I generated my first project with maven (because apparently some versions aren't available in the maven repo) so I used the newest version of the playn-archetype:

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7.1

which generated my project neatly. Then I changed the Android SDK to 17 instead of the generated 11 and run the project. But instead of the background image which is in the assets project of PlayN I only get a black screen with a little box in the corner of my Phone which contains ERROR ERROR. Neither LogCat or any other Logging feature in IntelliJ-IDEA showed any exception or error so far. [here](http://daraku.de/stuff/pics/Screenshot_error.png) is a picture of the screen

Has anyone encountered and fixed this problem? Thank you for your help!

Stuff I'm using:

- Android SDK 17
- Java Development Kit 7 update 25
- IntelliJ IDEA 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution for this with the help of the guys on googlecode.

first of I needed to set the Variables to the different things I use: (to complete the picture I will write all my variables I added)

set **%JAVA_HOME%** to your Java folder (should be JDK 1.6)
add to Path **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**

set **%ANDROID_HOME%** to your Android SDK folder
add to Path **%ANDROID_HOME%\tools** and **%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools**

set **%M2_HOME%** to your Maven folder
add to Path **%M2_HOME%\bin**

let maven generate your project with the playn-archetype

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.googlecode.playn -DarchetypeArtifactId=playn-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.7.1

then add to the top-level pom (MyGame\pom.xml) the following code (text in double star is the things you must add)

```
<properties>
   <playn.version>1.7.1</playn.version>
   **<android.maven.version>3.6.0</android.maven.version>**
</properties>
```

and

```
<modules>
   <module>assets</module>
   <module>core</module>
   **<module>android</module>**
</modules>
```

now you can run the project with

> mvn install -pl android -am

and run it on your phone with

> mvn -f android\pom.xml android:run

This should do the trick and if your phone is connected to the computer the android project with the background image should be visible on the display.